# Defining scope of a software pen test

Tags: penetration-test, java, server, client

If I own a software and I want to conduct a pen test with pen testers, should I define the scope or do the pen testers assess the software first and they define the scope? How does scope definition happen?

Furthermore, does the term "full scope" exist? By "full scope", I mean pen testing the whole software without defining a scope for the pen testers.

Note: the software is java based  (java thick client to server)

Answer (score 1):

It's your software. You can define the scope, even if it is the entire thing.

The potential issue might be cost. The costs of testing some areas of the software might be so high and the time to complete might take so long, that the pen testers might advise on a smaller scope in order to stay within your budget.

Comment: ah okay, and when defining scope in a huge software, what the scope would be like? a written form of document listing the areas covered in the scope? if there's a good reference on how to define a scope that would be great!

Comment: Are you the software owner or a tester? There are well-established documents to guide testers.

Comment: @ethicalhacker For a fat client, that's usually the client software, as well as a list of IP addresses the software interacts with. So you could say something like "The entire fat client is in scope. The client communicates with a licensing server at 10.202.107.19 - that server is not in scope." By doing that, I as a pentester would know pretty well what i am supposed to test.

Comment: @schroeder I am software owner, not the tester.

Comment: @MechMK1, I see your point but still it's not clear for me how much should I detail the scope? like in your example, the entire fat client, is that enough? or should I specify for example: the login page of the fat client? the authentication/authorization mechanism for example? hope you understand my confusion.

Comment: @ethicalhacker "the entire fat client" is usually enough. But what matters is that the testers understand. Have a meeting with them, discuss the scope, make sure there is mutual understanding.

Comment: @MechMK1 but it's wrong to start a pen test without defining a scope, right? like just saying pen test my fat client app and that's it. it's a wrong approach I guess

Comment: @ethicalhacker "pentest my fat client" **is** a scope definition. You seem to believe that scope is defined within the application, but that's not true. Just saying the application is all that should be tested is already defining what is and isn't to be tested.

Comment: @MechMK1 yes that is what I was thinking of, and what I actually read over the internet, in some articles it is mentioned that scope should be well defined, for example defining which part of the app to include in the scope, or the authentication mechanism implemented, or the login page for example, and etc...

Comment: @ethicalhacker "Well-defined" means that all involved parties understand what the scope is, not that it is specified in excruciating detail. Say you contract a painter and tell him "Please paint my fence in eggshell white", then that is *well-defined*. You do not need the exact GPS coordinates of each corner of the fence down to each atom. Likewise, if you say "the whole app, but not this server", that is well-defined as well.